# Time estimation of tasks defined with normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

First of all, big stat noob here, so go easy on me :)

In a task scheduling setting, I'm trying to make a time estimation given a schedule.
So, suppose we have several tasks one after the other with a duration defined as a normal distribution. (not worrying about parralelism or scheduling or anything here, just N task following each other).

In this case, if each taks has a mean and an std dev, what about the whole planning.
Can it still be defined as a normal distribution or is it more complex than that?
And if so, I find pretty intuitive that the mean would just be the sum of the mean of all the tasks. But I have no clue about the std devs, how to go about that?

What terms or concept should I look for for "combining" normal distributions like this? (if there's even such a thing)

If you have any material about that, just the name of such an operation if that exist, I'd like to know a bit more.

If I try to put that in more generic terms (again, stat noob here), it's like drawing N random variables with each its own parameters, and summing the results right?
In this case, that would make sense (to me at least) that the means do add up, but I can't figure out what happens to the std devs...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, subject to two points:

- all normal distributions can take negative values, though your means may be so much larger than your standard deviations that this is unlikely in your case
- the addition of normally distributed random variables to give a normal distribution applies if the random variables are independent (in which case you can sum the variances - the squares of the standard deviations - to give the variance of the sum), or if they jointly have a multivariate normal distribution (in which case the variance of the sum also depends on the covariances), though not necessarily if they have some other kind of dependency

You can simply sum the expectations to give the expectation of the sum, and this works with all distributions, normal or not, dependent or not, providing that the expectations are finite.

Comment: Okay, good to know, many thanks.

(and yeah, of course this way of modeling things can lead to negative values, but I ended up wondering more about the impact of addition on the std_dev/var rather than the problem itself^^)